# Modular zero of a function

Tags: number-theory, functions, modular-arithmetic

Is there a quick and dirty way to find the modular zero of a function, such that f(x) = 0 (mod p), p being a prime.
E.g. f(x) = x^2 - 5x + 1 and p = 7. It's quite easy to find that for x = 6 the congruence holds.
But what if p is beyond 10,000,000? Cycling through x from 5 to whatever seems awkward.
(Note: we may assume that p is a valid prime so that there's an x for which the congruence holds.)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the characteristic isn't $\;2\;$ you can use the usual formula for the roots of a quadratic:

$$x^2-5x+1=0\pmod 7\implies x_{1,2}=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{25-4}}2=\frac{5\pm0}2\pmod7=$$

$$=\frac52\pmod7=5\cdot4\pmod7=6\pmod7=-1\pmod7$$

so

$$x^2-5x+1=x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2\pmod7$$

With any other prime$\;\neq2\;$ you can use exactly the same formula

Comment: I'm sorry, but I seem to miss the point. I've tried to reproduce it with p = 37. But I can't get it to work properly, according to your description.

Comment: @Oliver1012 Let us work with arithmetic modulo $\;37\;$ . We need to find out whether the discriminant $\;\Delta=b^2-4ac=21\;$ is a square in this case. Using Legendre's symbol: $$\left(\frac{21}{37}\right)=\left(\frac{3}{37}\right)\left(\frac{7}{37}\right)=\left(\frac13\right)\left(\frac{2}{7}\right)=1\cdot1=1$$ and thus it is a square, and in fact $\;13^3=21\pmod{37}\;$ , so the roots are $$\frac{5\pm13}2=9,\,-4=33\pmod{37}$$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... I need to find the discriminant = b^2 - 4ac and check if Legendre(discriminant | prime) = 1. If so, apply Shanks-Tonelli to find x in x^2 = a (mod p), a being the discriminant.

Comment: @Oliver1012 That's correct, though in many cases the ST algorithm is way too much.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated!